# AngularJS and Parse – e2e test does not wait for request

Tags: angularjs, parse-platform, jasmine, angularjs-e2e, karma-jasmine

I am developing an application using AngularJS and the Parse SDK (parse.com).

In my unit tests I mock the calls to the Parse SDK, so that works just fine. The problem is that I want to have e2e tests as well. My Jasmine e2e test just checks whether the items loaded from the Parse service are rendered. However the test does not wait for the Parse SDK to complete its HTTP call.

Is there any way to make this happen? The project is setup with Yeoman 1.1.2, so I am using AngularJS 1.2.6 and karma ~0.10.8 and karma-jasmine ~0.1.4.

Any tip is greatly appreciated.